# What is the order of the multiplicative group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

According to Lagrange's Theorem, the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_{54})^\times$ cannot contain a subgroup of which order:

**A**: $9$
**B**: $18$
**C**: $6$
**D**: $12$

I think that it is **D** because $12$ is not a factor of $54$.

Comment: The order of $(\mathbb Z/54)^\times$ is not $54$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Euler totient function, we know that the order of the multiplicative group of $ \mathbb{Z}_{n}=\phi (n)$
Which is given by the formula

$\phi(n)=n\prod_{p | n} \frac{p-1}{p}$

Hence

$\phi(54)=54\frac{3-1}{3} \frac{2-1}{2} =18 $

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of the subgroup must divide the order of the group since 12 does not divide 18
The answer is D

Comment: where did you get the numbers for the fractions from?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_{54}$ has 18 elements. Just compute the Eulerian phi function.

Answer (score 2):

Since the underlying set of $G:=(\Bbb Z_{54})^\times$ is (equivalent to)

$$\{a\in\Bbb N\mid \gcd(a,54)=1\land a\in\{0,1,2,\dots, 53\}\},$$

by definition, its order is $\varphi (54)=2^0(2-1)3^2(3-1)=18$, where $\varphi $ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

The divisors of $18$ are $1,2,3,6,9,18$, so, by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), $12$ cannot be the order of a subgroup of $G$.

Hence the answer is indeed **D**, but not for the reason you stated, which, as pointed out in the comments, is flawed.

Comment: I understand Lagragnge's Theorem but I don't understand how to compute the order with Euler's Totient Function.

Comment: Euler's totient function when evaluated at $n$ is the number of natural numbers between $0$ and $n-1$, inclusively, that are coprime to $n$. But this is precisely the cardinality of the underlying set of $G$, @butterchi.